# Effective way to block any one from reverse proxying your site

Tags: php, nginx

Apperently a new thing to attack SEO on websites, is to reverse proxy the site with a new domain, we have had a case of this, reveled by google search console.

Is there an effective way to block this from happening either thrue nginx, or php?

Comment: The hits from their proxy to your site should all have the same source IP, which you can [deny with nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html).

Comment: Hi ye did that, but guess i got to wait until Cloudflare cache runs out, sadly.